# How can I eliminate left recursion in the following grammar?

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax, context-free-grammar

Here's the grammar, which is supposed to describe a language of nested braces with commas as delimiters:

```
L ::= {L} | L,L |
```

A few more examples of strings I'd expect the grammar to accept and reject:

Accept:

```
{,{,,{,}},,{,}}
{{{{}}}}
{,{}}
```

Reject:

```
{}{}
{,{}{}}
{{},{}
```

Comment: what tooling are you using to get the left recursion error from?

Comment: Not homework, just trying to work my way through a book on compilers. For fun, I swear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done by hand:

L ::= `{` L `}` | `{` L `}` `,` | `,` L | ε

Or, instead of just winging it we could use a more systematic approach and apply the algorithm from Wikipedia on [removing immediate left recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%5Frecursion#Removing_immediate_left_recursion):

L ::= `{` L `}` L<sub>1</sub> | L<sub>1</sub>
L<sub>1</sub> ::= ε | `,` L L<sub>1</sub>

Comment: Can't think of a way to derive `{{},}` from this grammar

Comment: @litb: the outer {} is the first rule {L} the {}, is firstly second rule L,L with the first of those {} and the second empty.

Comment: nod, I only just clicked you where meaning JK's grammar vs. wkf's my bad.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that grammar won't accept your first example, since it requires the commas to be after the close brace and before the open brace.  I would suggest to re-write it as

```
L::= {L} | ,L
```

This won't get rid of the left recursion, but it will at least match your acceptable answers.

Comment: Not true. His grammar will accept `{,}`, where the ',' is produced by L1=L2,L3 with L2 and L3 being empty.

Comment: Your right - I didn't realise that that was the point of the empty rule at the end